# MySQL trigger with incremental part

Tags: mysql

I am using a MySQL database and want to create a trigger before any insert on the table 'jobs'

My schema is the following :

```
+-------------+     +--------------+
|    jobs     |     |   machines   |
+-------------+     +--------------+
| job_id      |  ___| machine_id   |
| job_machine |_|   | machine_name |
| job_name    |     +--------------+
| job_start   |
+-------------+
```

There is a foreign key between jobs.job_machine and machines.machine_id

job_start is a datetime and will be used to fill job_name. But it will be formated like this

```
select DATE_FORMAT(job_start, "%y%m%d") from jobs where NEW.job_id;
```

I want job_name to be the concatenation of job_start + job_machine + increment. I will explain.

By example if the jobs inserted is

```
+--------+-------------+-----------------------+----------+
| job_id | job_machine |       job_start       | job_name |
+--------+-------------+-----------------------+----------+
|      1 |           3 | '2015-09-18 14:20:00' |          |
+--------+-------------+-----------------------+----------+
```

job_name will be : 15091831

But if a similar job is created the same day on the same machine it will be 15091832

I have

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `myTable`.`jobs_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `jobs` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    select concat((select DATE_FORMAT(job_start, "%y%m%d") from jobs where job_id=NEW.job_id) , (select job_machine from jobs where job_id = NEW.job_id));
END
```

But I am not very sure about the incremental part. What is the best way to proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First determine the current increment value, then use it for both the id and name:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `myTable`.`jobs_BEFORE_INSERT`
 BEFORE INSERT ON `jobs` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE next_id integer;
 -- select the current highest id and increment it
SET @next_id := (select max(job_id)+1
    from jobs 
    where DATE_FORMAT(job_start, '%y%m%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NEW.job_start, '%y%m%d') 
        and job_machine = NEW.job_machine);
-- if it is the first job for this machine this day then make it nr 1
IF ISNULL(@next_id) THEN
    SET @next_id := 1;
END IF;
-- then set your new row accordingly
SET NEW.job_id = @next_id;
SET NEW.job_name = concat(DATE_FORMAT(NEW.job_start, '%y%m%d'), job_machine, @next_id);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger logic is incomplete.  For instance, you are not setting any values in `new`, so the trigger does nothing.

I think the following does what you want:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `myTable`.`jobs_BEFORE_INSERT`
     BEFORE INSERT ON `jobs` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    select new.job_id := concat(DATE_FORMAT(new.job_start, '%y%m%d'), new.job_machine,
                                RIGHT(MAX(job_name), 1) + 1)
    from jobs j
    where j.job_start >= date(new.job_start) and
          j.job_start < date(new.job_start) + interval 1 day and
          j.job_machine = new.job_machine
END
```